# jQuery.stop() Timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making something where I want the player to `.stop()` with jQuery but after 2 seconds be able to move again. This is what I have tried already.

Using Boolean's to check the collision and if so set it to false and not let him move, that did not work, `setTimeout` won't work either. Here is my timeout is it wrong or just wont work?

Here is my code,

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#character').stop();    
}, 2700);
```

Comment: Why don't you call your code recursively? If you want to keep stopping and starting his movement, you can use clearTimeout to ensure the event is retired every 2700ms

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but its not working it lets the animations play it just wont let it animate/move, anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout);

like

```
//in a shared scope
var timer;

//then
timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $('#character').stop();
}, 2700);

//then later
cleatTimeout(timer)
```